# Use authlogic to find the User record based on an associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, associations, authlogic

Typically, with Authlogic, you would authenticate with some unique identifier (e.g. email or username) and a password. Authlogic does this by first finding the record by the identifier (`User.find_by_email_address(email)` or similar), then calling then `.authenticate` method on the returned object, which checks the password against the record.

What I want to do is change the way Authlogic finds the record (at a finer level than just changing the field it uses). My use case requires that the `email_address` column (in this case) is in an associated child model.

Essentially, I want to ask Authlogic to find my `User` record based on the presence of an associated `Subscriber` model that is uniquely identified by the `email_address` that is provided.

Has anyone seen Authlogic accommodate this?

Answer (score 0):

You might probably want to configure a different #[login_field](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/Login/Config#login_field-instance_method).

Comment: `#login_field` only accepts a symbol for another field in the DB, not for one in an associated model. It's looking more like I'll need to re-define the method that does the finding.

Comment: Does it want a field in the db or a method? If it only cares about a method (you need to check the source code), then you can simply creates a method that returns the result of the association.

Comment: it needs a field. It does find_by_xyz() on the main User record. I may need to find that exact method and override it to do a find with a join and use conditions on the associated record.